# how can we iterate datarow array in foreach loop

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

In dr i select the 102 rows from datatable.

Now i need to loop the first 100 dr values.I use the following for each loop its shows error like " cannot convert type datarow to int)

First i can take the 100 rows and process some logic after that logic i need to remove from the first 100 values from dr.after that i need to pick up the remaining 2 values.

```
DataRow[] dr = dtSourceDetail.Select("fld_description = '"+desc+"' ");
foreach(int i in dr.Take(100))
{
  //process some logic

  //here need to remove the first row from dr.  
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Hey @User have a look at the solution provided by me see if that helps and acknowledge if you still face any issue with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type in the `foreach` to `DataRow`

```
DataRow[] dr = dtSourceDetail.Select("fld_description = '"+desc+"' ");
foreach(DataRow i in dr.Take(100))
{
  //process some logic

  //here need to remove the first row from dr.  
}
```

A `foreach` will try and cast each item that it receives from the enumerator to the type that you provide in the statement. In this case you provide `int`. It receives the first `DataRow` and then tries to cast it, which is where it is failing.

Comment: can you please little bit elabrate on this

Comment: how can i remove the first 100 from dr after some logic was performed and as well as i need to loop that remaining two record too

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to the same question, maybe start another thread for that question.

Comment: @User To get the last 2 you can do a `Skip` so it would be `dr.Skip(100).Take(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Take` returns an enumerable of `DataRow` objects. Not an enumerable of `int`s. So the loop variable must be a `DataRow`:

```
DataRow[] dr = dtSourceDetail.Select("fld_description = '"+desc+"' ");
foreach(DataRow row in dr.Take(100))
{
}
```

Now that you have a single `row` you can access the column values of that row as usual.

```
int i = (int)row["some_int_column"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you.

```
DataRow[] dr = dtSourceDetail.Select("fld_description = '"+desc+"' ");
for (int i = 0; i < dr.count; i=i+100)
{
    foreach(DataRow i in dr.Skip(i).Take(100))
    {
        //process some logic
    }
}
```

First loop that is simple for loop is just the counter for us. Then next foreach loop we are taking `dr.Skip(i).Take(100)` that means it will take 100 for the first time next time it skips 100 and gives you next 100. Since you dont have 100 records it will give you the rest records.